# How can I fix: Unhandled Exception: type 'SocketException' is not a subtype of type 'String'?

Tags: flutter, dart

this function creates the error:

```
static Future<String> createTable() async {
try {
  var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
  map['action'] = 'CREATE_TABLE';
  final response = await http.post(ROOTurl, body: map);
  print('Create Table Response: ${response.body}');
  if (200 == response.statusCode) {
    return response.body;
  } else {
    return "error";
  }
} catch (e) {
  return "error"+e;
}}
```

full exception:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'SocketException' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Any way I can fix this?

Comment: Instead of 'return "error"+e' try to write 'return "error ${e.message}"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate a `String` with a non-string type

try this:

```
  try {
    //code throwing exceptions
  } on SocketException catch (e) {
    print('error ${e.message}');
  } catch (e) {
    //for other errors
    print('error ${e.toString()}');
  }
```

Comment: ${e.message} didn't work, ${e} did work thanks for that! But now this error shows up: I/flutter (17320): error SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 49958

Comment: now this is an error due to security and it has nothing to do with the question
but it is weird that it didn't work because the documentation says that the SocketException class has a message property(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/SocketException-class.html)

Comment: I fixed it by replacing 'localhost' from the url with my ip address now everything works. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Fenerbahce please look at the edit
the answer didn't work first because if you don't specify the exception type then the type will be abstract Exception which does not have a message property while SocketException has this property